# Planning my Singapore tour as a photographer

Tags: sightseeing, tips-and-tricks, photography, singapore, universal-studios

I am visiting singapore. I am a traveller + Photographer. I will arrive at 5.00 AM 14th Sep and Departure is 7.00 AM 16th. So I got only two days. I have booked a hotel from Geylang area (Without knowing it's a red light area). Anyway since I am interesting in looking at nice things here is the places I thought that I can cover within these two days. Please help me with planning according to the distance in between each other and average time it takes to see and take some photographs. All these places are not must. But Universal Studio and Singapore Flyer got more priority.

Singapore Flyer
http://www.singaporeflyer.com/unique-experiences/singapore-flight/
S$ 33
Best time Evening sunset + lights on

Sands Sky Park
http://www.marinabaysands.com/Sands-SkyPark/Tickets/
S$20

Universal Studio - Looks like whole day require
http://www.rwsentosa.com/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=TsR3qmTLECI%3d&tabid=962&mid=8113&language=en-US
S$68
Indeed expensive but massive experience

Merlion
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlion

Singapore Cable Car
http://www.sentosa.com.sg/en/attractions/imbiah-lookout/cable-car/
S$29

Underwarter World
http://www.sentosa.com.sg/en/attractions/siloso-point/underwater-world-singapore/
S$26

Marina Bay Sands Show
Free
http://singaporeplacestogo.blogspot.com/2011/06/marina-bay-sands-show-wonder-full.html

Please add if I missed any good place and if I can ignore some and see those I will agree with you. Also I want to know from where I can buy tickets, especially to Universal Studio. And Do I have to pay extra if I use my camera. Here is the plan in my mind.

14th - Friday -
Universal Studio,
Singapore Cable car,
Underwarter World,
Merlion

15th - Staurday -
Sands Sky Park,
Marina Bay,
Singapore Flyer,
And do some shopping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a photographers view I have to say I was really annoyed with the flyer, the curved windows made it difficult to get really high quality shots. And that is if there aren't too many reflections from people inside the cabin. Had I known this before I paid that very expensive ticket I would not have spent the money. Sky Park gave me way more, both as a backdrop from the ground and shooting from above.

I did not go to the Universal Studios, because I was told by fellow backpackers I met several times that it just isn't that much to see if you're not traveling with your family. That and the price made me skip it and instead took the amazing metro to the Singapore Botanical Gardens, and boy am I happy I did that, amazing place.

Another place not nearly mentioned enough is the Marina Bay area, I feel many people rush past this area to get to the Sky Park. It is possible to walk at the water front almost all the way around the Marina Bay.

Before rushing out to Sentosa island I suggest taking a look at the gateway. Along with the flyer you can also walk to/from the island from the CC29/NE1 "Harbour Front" metro station next to Viva City. This walkway was a great place for some shots.

My quick list of suggestions:

- **Singapore Botanical Gardens**
- **Sky Park** (and connecting giant shopping mall with skating rink)
- **Marina Bay area**
- **Harbour Front before/after taking the flyer**

For shopping electronics look up Sim Lim Square, just make sure you know what you want before you go there. They will say anything they can to sell you stuff. But If you know your stuff it's no problem to ignore that and simply haggle the price on the stuff they got. A walk between the amazing National Library to Sim Lim Square will take you past the Bugis area which houses lots of shopping.

So now I will leave you with the decision between Sentosa Island or "all the other things" which might extend the walk from National Library past Sim Lim Square to Little India area, if you're interested in that. Hope that helps a bit :D

EDIT: The Botanical Gardens are free but it costs a few SGD to get in to the Orchid Garden. There is also a food place in the garden if that makes planning any easier, however I did not have the opportunity to check the prices there.

Comment: Thanks Alendri. I really appreciate your suggestions based on your experience.

Comment: On my last day there I found a "Freshness Burger" restaurant, I frequented such a place in Tokyo many times. If the Singapore one is anything like that I recommend it, fresh squeezed juiced and everything nearly converted me from not thinking of burgers as a bad food. Salad, meat and potato aren't necessarily bad things after all :D http://www.hungrygowhere.com/review/107022/# says it pretty good. So for shopping and some food maybe check out the NEX mall, I never visited. Just walked past.

Answer (score 4):

As a local, I will highly recommend checking out [Wild Singapore](http://www.wildsingapore.com) and the areas **away** from the city centre. Contrary to our label of an ultra-modern concrete jungle, we have really beautiful natural sights due to our tropical climate. I would also recommend the following:

- **Little India** (if you're looking for something more gritty than Chinatown)
- **Geylang** (the city's red-light district. also a haven for awesome food)
- **Tanah Merah Ferry Terminal** (where lovebirds catch gorgeous sunsets)
- **Pulau Ubin** (formerly a rock quarry. also see those old *kampung* villages)
- **East Coast Park** (built on reclaimed land. where locals like us go for a barbecue, a skate or a jog. marathon routes usually go through the stretch)
- **Changi Point** (this is from Wild Singapore. at low tide, you'll be able to catch some corals)
- **Bukit Timah Nature Reserve** (where our highest point of 163.83m stands. climb the hill in the morning, then tuck into a local breakfast at Chun Tin Road close by)

And if you want to experience the local life of a Singaporean, drop by any of our coffee shops in our housing estate. Grab a coffee (we say kopi - pronounced as *koh-pee*) or tea (we say teh - pronounced as *tay*) then watch the day go by with the *aunties* (local lingo, usually married ladies in their late 50s/60s) sitting around gossiping and the *uncles* (local lingo, usually men in their late 50s/60s) reading the Chinese newspapers.